# Get form data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to save the data of fields in simple vars. I only need the input values

```
<input type="text" id="login_email" class="large" name="login_email" value="">

<input type="submit" name="submit.x" value="Entrar" class="btn large">
```

How can I get data of login_email box and save it into a var?

Edit: The problem: the elementid "login_email" is static. I need some that when the user types the text the code captures it and save it into a var.

Comment: If it's a form, jQuery has `$('form').serialize()` that gets everything for you ready to be sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture what's being entered in an input, with jQuery, you can bind to the `.keyup()` event and save the value to a variable in the global / higher scope (eg outside of the event, or document.ready()):

**Example:**

```js
var email;
$('#login_email').keyup(function(e) {
  email = $(this).val();
  $('#results').html(email);
});
```

```css
#results {
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="login_email" />

<span id="results"></span>
```

Comment: It can work but, how can I save the var when the user leaves the box ???

Comment: The `var email` in the above instance still contains whatever was written in the input (even after the input loses focus)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `value` property and the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event of [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement):

```
var loginEl = document.getElementById('login_email');
var loginEmail;

loginEl.onchange = function emailChanged() {
    loginEmail = loginEl.value;
}
```

Comment: The problem: the elementid "login_email" is static. I need some that when the user types the text the code captures it and save it into a var.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english :S

Comment: @EnriqueGarcía - you should update your post with that information